# Vary Excel text field based on values in row

Tags: excel

In my job I have to review the work of several other techs.  The process they need to complete goes across days and sometimes weeks through multiple apps and databases, which is why the review process is needed to keep billing straight.  In each Step of the process (columns) the techs are given a pass (1) or a fail (0).  This is averaged and converted into a percentage for a score.  The final column is reserved for the review comments.  This is where we put in what was wrong with each job to assist in improving the tech's performance.  There is another worksheet (tab) where the Review Comments are combined with tech name and date to show an aggregate of the month.  On this worksheet the manager can select a tech and a month then sort by Review Comments.  This allows the manager/tech to see specific problem areas for targeted training.  The problem is in the review comments as multiple reviewers use different verbiage to indicate the problem, which inhibits effective sorting. Getting everyone to say the exact same thing is problematic.  Now to my question/problem: I would like the Review Comments cell to use specific text to indicate the Steps missed.  As we have over 20 steps in our process a simple, but long IF statement with every contingency would probably exceed the limits of excel.  Any body have any ideas?

[image: Sample Review Worksheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
L2: =TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(G2:K2=0,$G$1:$K$1,""))
```

[image]

Of, if you need to have the 100% show, you need to just test for that first.

In your example, you could use:

```
 =IF(SUM(G2:K2) = 5, "100%",TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(G2:K2=0,$G$1:$K$1,"")))
```

Comment: This works.  Thank you.  Now I just have to learn more about textjoin.  I've never seen that one before.

Comment: I made a couple slight changes.  Sometimes they may get a 100% and only complete steps 1 and 3.  In those cases we put a "-" to indicate the step was not needed, but we verified it.  To verify they have 100%, I do an average as the "-" is text and is not counted.  Also, I am going to add a hidden column below the header and use that as my verbose logging row, so the final looks like this: =IF(AVERAGE(G4:AB4) = 1, "100%",TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(G4:AB4=0,$G$3:$AB$3,""))).  Thank you so much for your answer and time.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a collection of the key phrases as items, the errors, and then doing an instr to look through the collection for the item (the error keyword) in the comments. Each item matched in the collection could the be added or add to their count of that phrase. So the end result is something like. That way you can see how many tiomes an error is mentioned?

name  Error name 1, Error name2 etc as headers and the rows below with each techs score